# C# Omits Milliseconds When Retrieving From DataBase

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql

I have a Microsoft SQL database that has datetime columns with in "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm" format. And I am retrieving tables from this database on .NET through a stored procedure just selects these columns and returns. When I execute the stored procedure on Microsoft SQL, I get the milliseconds like I am supposed to. But if I retrieve these on .NET, the milliseconds are omitted IF it is "000". I get milliseconds just fine if they are anything else than "000". Otherwise, I get "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss"

Since I get the milliseconds just fine on Microsoft SQL execution even if they are "000", I figure that .NET is fiddling with them. What would be the ideal way to resolve this problem? I want to have milliseconds being shown even if it's "000"

Comment: Seems like a simple formatting issue to me. Did you apply a format when you list your time values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DateTime is a binary format and doesn't "have zeros" or anything like that. It always contains a number that resolves to a year, month, day, hour, minute, second, and thousandths of second, whether it is displayed or not, whether it is zero or not.

Your issue is with display-- the conversion of the date/time to a string. You are probably performing the conversion implicitly (for example, by viewing the variable in the Watch pane), and when you do that, the framework will pick the format for you. You just need to be explicit about the format you want, using either [standard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.85).aspx) or [custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) format strings. For example:

```
var dateString = myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Comment: Thanks, explicitly stating the format I want to use at the time of retrieval or returning allowed me to have the miliseconds be shown.